# Macbook 10.9.5 Firefox freeze

Tags: macos, firefox

After updating OS X on my Macbook 2011 to 10.9.5 I've started facing Firefox (32.0.3) freezing for a minute when macbook is resumed from suspend. Does anyone have thoughts, where to look for a cause of that? As far as I know, no other software is affected.

Comment: From what OX version did you update?

Comment: That kinda suggests 10.9.4 to 10.9.5, which was released on Sept. 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably well know FF had a rough road recently.

Starting with FF 32.0.0 they got up to 32.0.1, 32.0.2 and 32.0.3 in one week while trying to solve a problem that  shows up as heavy CPU loading and sluggish behavior.

They are still working on resolving the issues with last release.

Best you can do is disable all add-on and extensions to test if it gets better.

FYI:

Here is my Console log with FF 32.0.3 Start UP.

```
kernel[0]: firefox (map: 0xffffff80384f42d0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80384f42d0, region 0x7fff8cc00000->0x7fff8ce00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.

kernel[0]: firefox (map: 0xffffff8038d30d20) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8038d30d20, region 0x7fff8cc00000->0x7fff8ce00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.

firefox[602]: stat on /Users/Buscar/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/2l6bevrl.default/sessionstore.js: No such file or directory
```

And the associated Start UP times (from FF Health Report).

[image]